# resizing image in python and converting to np.array increases the channel dim

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have a batch of 256x256x3 images. Batch Sized = 256.

> ```
> x_train_n.append(image)
> x_train_n2 = np.array(x_train_n)
> ```

When I check shape of the image, it is = 256x256x3.
However shape of x_train_n2 = 256x256x256x***4***

Why does the channel size change?

Comment: whats the datatype of x_train_n ? and whats the original shape of it ?

Comment: Its an Empty list.  x_train_n = []

Comment: the probably one of ur image, has 4 channels. so all of the images are given that empty channel at the end.. check the shape of all the images ur read..

Answer (score 1):

Image Resize in Python adds an extra channel. So its required to cut off the last channel.

```
x_train_n2[:,:,:,0:3]
```

Just found it out, it will solve it.